# Queries creation from method name in Spring JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch record based on event type and last updated user so i am writing a method to fetch data in SpringData JPA.

Below is the code for reference:

```
List<StrataLog> getEventTypeAndUserLastUpdatedOrderByLoggerLevelAscAndUoidAsc(String eventType,
            String userLastUpdated);
```

**I am getting below error:**

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property asc found for type String!
>   *List getEventTypeAndUserLastUpdatedOrderByLoggerLevelAscAndUoidAsc(String
>   eventType,            String userLastUpdated);*

Expected Output should be it should return rows from the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Order by multiple properties you should not add *And* between the properties

This should work:

```
List<StrataLog> findAllByEventTypeAndUserLastUpdatedOrderByLoggerLevelAscUoidAsc(String eventType,String userLastUpdated);
```

But as you can see the method-name is getting quit complex, you should consider using a `@Query` or use `Sort` as extra parameter